# Use next-i18next translations inside of a node.js

Tags: next.js

I am using next-i18next package for my next.js project. Right now I am sending out creating email functionality which takes places server-side and I would like to consume the same translation files that I already use for the frontend.

Does next-i18next provide any functionality that would allow me to consume the translations similar to how I do it on frontend?

Answer (score 0):

If you've set up next-i18next properly, you are able to use `req.i18n.t`;

```js
const nextI18NextMiddleware = require('next-i18next/middleware').default;
...

server.use(nextI18NextMiddleware(nextI18next));

server.get('/custom', (req, res) => {
  ...
  res.json({
    text: req.i18n.t('Text here'),
    lng: req.i18n.language,
  });
});
```